# Accessing in lazarus to a mdb file already opened by another program

Tags: delphi, ms-access, lazarus

I'm doing an application to show data from a mdb file, it works on a copy of the db, but, when I try to use the one that updates the data, it tells me that the database is already in use.

I use an odbc connection with this configuration:

```
Driver = 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)'
Params.Strings = (
      'DBQ=Data.mdb'
      'Locale Identifier=1031'
      'ExtendedAnsiSQL=1'
      'CHARSET=ansi'
    )
```

Is there any way to read this mdb file, the copy is not an option, I need to read every 10 seconds and the file is ... more than 100MB.

Than you very much.

Comment: It seems that you are stuck on the sharing aspect of Access databases? Please read this [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2c24eb08-bee1-453e-be8e-455f847c5c74?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Comment: You really need to use a  database server

Comment: Whatever other app is using the database needs to use it shared (non-exclusively) in order for this to work. Apparently, it isn't (it has it open for exclusive use).

Comment: Have you tried opening the database before that other program starts? It might then open it in a shared mode, or it might throw an error (or even crash). But it's worth a try.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with some of this solutions.